# Start from another min value when max value is reached on Postgres Sequence

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, alembic

I have this Sequence defined in sqlalchemy for postgres

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
user_id_sequence = sa.Sequence(name='user_id_seq',
                               start=100000,
                               increment=10,
                               maxvalue=100000000,
                               cache=100)
```

For some business logic I can't have a sequence of numbers with an increment of 1. What I want to do is after we reach `maxvalue` the sequence starts over again but now with `start` parameters as 100001. In this way the sequence will not collide with other already generated numbers and also I can re use the sequence without worrying about running out of numbers.

Is this possible?

Comment: I've found out `pseudo_encrypt` postgres function might be useful here

Answer (score 1):

On Postgres Documentation there is a really nice function for generating random numbers without worrying about collisions. In this way I can use a normal sequence generator and always use the function for masquerade the original number.

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Pseudo_encrypt

Answer (score 0):

This is the final solution

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.pseudo_encrypt(value bigint) returns bigint AS $$
DECLARE
l1 int;
l2 int;
r1 int;
r2 int;
i int:=0;
BEGIN
 l1:= (value >> 16) & 65535;
 r1:= value & 65535;
 WHILE i < 3 LOOP
   l2 := r1;
   r2 := l1 # ((((1366 * r1 + 150889) % 714025) / 714025.0) * 32767)::bigint;
   l1 := l2;
   r1 := r2;
   i := i + 1;
 END LOOP;
 return ((r1 << 16) + l1);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql strict immutable;
```

```
create sequence if not exists user_id_seq
as bigint
increment by 1
minvalue 1
maxvalue 1000000000
cache 100;
```

how to tested in SQL

```
-- generate 10 mill random id
select x, pseudo_encrypt(x) as encrypt
into temp table pseudo_encrypt_results
from generate_series(1,10000000) as x;

-- we should get 10 mill
select count(1) from pseudo_encrypt_results;

-- validate there are not repeated elements in temporary table
select encrypt as encrypt_1, encrypt as encrypt_2, count(*)
from pseudo_encrypt_results
group by encrypt_1, encrypt_2
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

How to use in Python with SQLALchemy

```
from sqlalchemy import func, Sequence
user_id = session.query(func.public.pseudo_encrypt(
                Sequence('user_id_seq').next_value())).first()[0]
```